# How to stored null value in OpenCSVSerde or avoid quote char in LazySimpleSerde at Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-serde

I have a question about TBLProperties in Hive for OpenCSVSerde and SimpleLazySerDe.

Data file stored in text file (generated by SQOOP)

Table properties

1. Stored data as OpenCSVSerde
2. separatorChar by `|`
3. quoteChar by `"`
4. escapeChar by `\\`

The problem is `null` value are display as empty string `""`. Then I found this

[Writing columns having NULL as some string using OpenCSVSerde - HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058435/writing-columns-having-null-as-some-string-using-opencsvserde-hive)

I've try to follow on that topic, but got one issue if pipe `|` stored in the content then column will be shifting.

1. Create OpenCSVSerde table

```
CREATE TABLE `opencsv_serde`(   
  `a` string,
  `b` string,
  `c` string
)   
ROW FORMAT SERDE    
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'  
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (  
  'quoteChar'='\"',     
  'separatorChar'='|',
  'escapeChar'='\\'
)   
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT   
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'    
OUTPUTFORMAT    
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

2. Create LazySimpleSerDe table (I think quoteChar won't work)

```
CREATE TABLE `lazysimple_serde`(    
  `a` string,
  `b` string,
  `c` string
)   
ROW FORMAT SERDE    
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (  
  'field.delim'='|',    
  'serialization.format'='|',
  'escapeChar'='\\',
  'quoteChar'='\"'
)

STORED AS INPUTFORMAT   
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'    
OUTPUTFORMAT    
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'  
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='');
```

3. Insert data into `opencsv_serde`

```
insert into opencsv_serde
select "a|a", "b", '"c|c"' union all
select "d|d", "e", null;
```

4. Select data from `opencsv_serde` [result from opencsv_serde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZaNA.png)
5. Insert data from `opencsv_serde` to `lazysimple_serde`

```
insert into lazysimple_serde
select * from opencsv_serde
```

6. Check result from `lazysimple_serde`
   [result from lazysimple_serde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIGfv.png)

Found column shifting in LazySimpleSerDe

I need to know about how to stored null in OpenCSVSerDe or prevent column shifting in LazySimpleSerDe

Thank you